# Train CNN with large dataset with data in a Google bucket

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-storage, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to train a CNN on a segmentation task (classify all pixels in two classes: soil or not soil). In order to do this, I have input images with a lot of channels (approx. 47) and label masks. I have all training/testing/validation data stored in a Google bucket because my virtual machine does not have space on the disk to store all that information. I found function `ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory()` from `tensorflow`, but I don't have all data in a local directory.

I'm trying to find a way that I can download maybe 5 images at a time in my local memory, and the generator will be "filled" with those 5 images, I remove them and download the next 5. Is there a solution for something like that?

I already have a function I can recurrently call to download the images. Thanks in advance.